# stuck with building a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

The question goes like this:
build the recursive function `bool isEven(int a, int b)` that figures out if there's an even/odd amount of occurrences of `b` in `a`.

`for example:
isEven(9545, 4) returns false
isEven(9545, 5) returns true`

I'm wondering what is the edge case for this problem, I thought of disassembling the number into group of subsets of `b` and check every subset recursively if it's even/odd but I got stuck with building this program.

Would appreciate your help,

**Update:** thought lots about it but without too much success - I can't figure out what's the edge case, what's the background idea of the recursion. this is what I did so far:

```
void main() {

    int n, d;

    cin >> n >> d;

    if(isEven(n, d))
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;;
}

bool isEven(int n, int d)
{
    int dgtsnum = digitsInNum(n);
    if (dgtsnum == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; 2 * i < dgtsnum; i++)
            powerset(2 * i, n);
    }
}

int powerset(int i, int j)
{
}

int digitsInNum(int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 10;
    while (n / ((int)j) >= 1)
    {

        i++;
        j *= 10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: 1- Post your attempt, 2 - chose a tag, Java OR c

Comment: "occurrences of b in a" is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool isEven(int a, int b){//a, b >= 0 (AND 9 >= b)
    if(a < 10)
        return a != b;
    return (a % 10 == b) ^ isEven(a / 10, b);
}
```

Comment: could understand the return a!=b, but couldn't get what you did at the second return. would appreciate your brief explanation!

Comment: Do you  understand Exclusive OR (`^`)? [EOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: nevermind, I got that you separate each digit of 'a' in every step. then making long XOR between all elements. while the truths are even the result would be negative and vice versa...

thank you so much!

Comment: `(a % 10 == b)`  meant that a number of last digit matches? , `isEven(a / 10, b)` meant that the rest of the numbers can be even judged?  Two of the proposition holds true when conflicting.